# ASP.NET Entity Framework Using Trim() in where clause not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have this line of code:

```
 var community = dbCommunity.Data.Where(m => m.community.Trim() == id.id).FirstOrDefault();
```

id.id is "TorontoCanada" but in my database I have them saved as "Toronto Ontario", what I am trying to do is Trim the white space for the data column. I tried Trim() but this returns null.

Please Help!

Comment: Go and look up with [`Trim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) actually does and you will see why it doesn't work.

Comment: `Trim` method does not remove spaces from inside the string. It removes spaces from front and end of the string. You need to use replace method to replace spaces with empty string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need trim() here, you need Replace(" ", ""). Also, trim() deletes the whitespace from both ends of a string, and is hence not usable in your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation of `Trim()` says:

> Removes all leading and trailing white-space characters from the current String object.

I suggest you to use `"".Replace(" ", string.Empty);`.
Not sure about how performatic this is going to be